# How can I configure a new IDataBus implementation which has a dependency which needs to be injected in NServiceBus?

Tags: dependency-injection, nservicebus

I want to replace the default `IDataBus` implementation (which writes to the filesystem) with one which writes to a db (so it can run on AWS).  To this end I have a config extension:

```
public static class ConfigureSqlServerDataBus
{
    public static Configure SqlServerDataBus(this Configure config)
    {
        var dataBus = new SqlServerDataBus();
        config.Configurer.RegisterSingleton<IDataBus>(dataBus);
        return config;
    }
}
```

to allow me to configure the bus.  But obviously my `SqlServerDataBus` has a dependency on something which tells it where to write (An `IRepository` implementation in this case).

Usually I would ask for the dependency through the constructor, but as the config of the service bus is done through the `IWantCustomInitialization` which will use `Activator` to create the instance I can't.  My understanding is that NServiceBus will use property injection to satisfy the dependencies but it doesn't seem to do this.  I have a couple of calls like this after my configuration is done:

```
Configure
.With()
.DefineEndpointName("SomeName")
.DefaultBuilder()
.DBSubcriptionStorage()
.XmlSerializer()
.SqlServerDataBus()
.MsmqTransport()
    .IsTransactional(true)
.UnicastBus()
.LoadMessageHandlers()
.CreateBus()
.Start(() => Configure.Instance.ForInstallationOn<NServiceBus.Installation.Environments.Windows>().Install());


Configure.Instance.Configurer.ConfigureComponent<RepositoryImplementation>(ComponentCallModelEnum.None);
Configure.Instance.Configurer.ConfigureComponent<SqlServerDataBus>(ComponentCallModelEnum.None);
```

but my setters for the `SqlServerDataBus` are never called, although the Put method is.

Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't change the configuration after the bus has already been started. To move your config calls into the fluent initialization code, use the RunCustomAction method.

Alternatively, you can write a new class which implements INeedInitialization and make your config calls in there. This class will be invoked at the right time.

Comment: Finally got round to testing this today, and using the RunCustomAction and putting my `Configure.Instance.Configurer.ConfigureComponent<RepositoryImplementation>(ComponentCallModelEnum.None);` in there worked a treat.  Thanks.